# Variable scope in a nested ScrollView

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have a peculiar issue and I need help. I have nested two scrollviews in react-native. The idea is to have like a chat interface where messages are shown with their replies which is based on an `id`. It was working fine and I don't know what happened. The code below

```
<ScrollView automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}>
          {feedlist &&
            feedlist
              .sort((a, b) => (Number(a.date) > Number(b.date) ? 1 : -1))
              .map(({ date, message, id }, index) => (
                <View
                  key={index}
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "rgb(245,245,245)",
                    marginVertical: 5,
                    ...
                  }}
                >
                  ...
              ))}
          <ScrollView>
            {replyset &&
              replyset
                .sort((a, b) => (Number(a.date) > Number(b.date) ? 1 : -1))
                .filter((item) => item.id === id)
                .map((item, index) => (
                  ...
                ))}
          </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

So somewhere in the second scrollview the is a filter by id which has lost scope somehow. When I move it into the the function of the map it gains scope and gives me repetition and messy data. This is the out put I am expecting[image]. Please advice

Comment: You need to provide more info for us to help you out here. Please at least describe what your expected and actual output is, sample data, error messages, etc.

Comment: @BaconPancakes So I have a medical feedback system and I am trying to display Items from two tables such that they have and Id field in common. I want to fetch the reply from the doctor and put under the message of the patient. I don't know if there is an ideal way pf doing that. The error I get is from the filter in the second scrollview where it can't find the (id) in `item.id===id`